Check if the user is logged in to the Epic Games Launcher
I am launching epic's games in a c# project and while doing this, the epic games launcher opens first. when the launcher opens, I need to find out if a user is logged in or not.
I start the game with
string uri = "com.epicgames.launcher://apps/" + LaunchID + "?action=launch&silent=true";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = $"/C start {uri}",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true // Set to true if you want to hide the command prompt window
};

Process.Start(psi);

In steam someone do it with registers, but there is nothing like that on epic.
Can you guys help me?
